# How to install Kivy by using pip on CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, kivy

I am beginner to develop Android and iOS using Kivy, installing these package these package got successfully installed.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
```

When I install this package by using pip I got an error

```
python -m pip install pygame and pip install Kivy
[pkg-config.exe - Application Error The Application is enable to start correctly 0xc000007b][1]
```

And On Command Prompt screen Show

I have upload 1st and 8th image:

[image: I have upload 1st and 8th image]

This image is last image of error:

[image: This image is last image of error]

How can I solve this issue?

```
pip version pip -- 20.1.1
python version -- 3.8.0
```

I have also add this question on [group google](https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/c/KbN4ObXuWAk)

Comment: answered in g groups: "1) the current release version of Kivy (1.11.1) does not install under Python 3.8.  Use Python 3.7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have solve this problem by change python version 3.6 it's working pe

Comment: It is Main Answer of Every Problem in Python You Have To Do Only Change Python Version And Nothing

Answer (score 1):

try using this. Worked for me in the same case.

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

worked on python 3.8.2 both 32 and 64 bit, os: win10

Comment: if this doesn't work try      python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1

Comment: dear first i want to say thank you fro help but i am not able to import kivy module again show same

Comment: try installing it like this

python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*
python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*